# Spring ставиться на Eclispe?

Tags: spring, eclipse

Хотел давно установить Sping Framework, но в интернете есть только, установка Spring на Eclipse. Так Spring это отдельный фреймворк или дополнение к Eclipse?

Comment: Это отдельный фреймвёрк, не имеющий к еклипсу никакого отношения. Но еклипс в свою очередь даёт возможность составлять программки на основе спринга. Ибо спринг достаточно популярен и  никто бы не простил еклипсу отсутствия поддержки спринга. Впрочем другие ИДЕ тоже поддерживают спринг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это фреймворк [spring.io](https://spring.io/). Существуют плагины для Eclipse и Idea для поддержки контекста, компонентов, аннотаций и других, связанных со spring, вещей.